# Live Server cannot load other pages with Apache 404 error

Tags: php, apache2, codeigniter-3

I'm using Google VM instances on Google Cloud Platform for running my live server. I'm also using CodeIgniter to build of my server. It can load the default route when entering the page but when going to other routes, it shows Apache 404 error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at 35.186.147.249 Port 80

My Apache config file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I looked up online and most people say it is an Apache problem but I'm not too sure. I'll share any of the files in order to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The line  DocumentRoot /var/www/html determinate the base of your files, I reviewed the IP that you put and i can see the next folder and access correctly:

- j/
- medical-survey/
- temp/

Here is the [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) to understand more about DocumentRoot, so you can define where you require the default folder route for your web files. In case you require to have different links of your web development you can follow this [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04/) to configure the virtual hosts. Hope this is what you were looking for.